# getView() position is repeating in BaseAdapter -Android

Tags: android, baseadapter

In my Android Application I am showing a list of Cards. I am using BaseAdapter. All cards are visible to me on the ListView but I am getting an issue.

`getView()` is called with repeated positions due to the first card not showing the correct image. It is using the image from the 2nd to last card. I spent a day to fix it. I visited many stackoverflow answers, but no luck. Help me please.

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.wallet_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.cardIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_wallet_card);
            holder.cardName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_wallet_card_name);
            holder.cardPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_wallet_card_price);
            holder.cancel  =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        WalletRowItem rowItem = (WalletRowItem) getItem(position);

        if(rowItem.getCard_name().equalsIgnoreCase("Kiss")){

           holder.cardIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
            holder.cardName.setText("Kiss");
            holder.cardPrice.setText("");
            int bg_red=Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getBackground_red());
            int bg_green=Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getBackground_green());
            int bg_blue=Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getBackground_blue());
            holder.colorbg=Color.rgb(bg_red, bg_green, bg_blue);
            holder.cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mViewClickListener.onImageClicked(position);
                }
            });
        }else{
                holder.cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(context).load(rowItem.getCardImage_url()).error(R.drawable.success_icon).placeholder(R.drawable.plus_icon_actionbar).into(holder.cardIcon);

            holder.cardName.setText(rowItem.getCard_name());

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(rowItem.getCard_price())) {
                holder.cardPrice.setText("$" + rowItem.getCard_price());
            }else{
                holder.cardPrice.setText("$" + "0.0");
            }

            int bg_red=Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getBackground_red());
            int bg_green=Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getBackground_green());
            int bg_blue=Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getBackground_blue());
            holder.colorbg=Color.rgb(bg_red, bg_green, bg_blue);
        }

        //Make a shape drawable to make list_item corner rounded .
        ShapeDrawable footerBackground = new ShapeDrawable();
        float[] radii = new float[8];
        radii[0] = 10 ;
        radii[1] = 10 ;
        radii[2] = 10 ;
        radii[3] = 10 ;
        footerBackground.setShape(new RoundRectShape(radii, null, null));
        footerBackground.getPaint().setColor(holder.colorbg);
        convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(footerBackground);

        int red=Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getTitle_red());
        int green=Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getTitle_green());
        int blue=Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getTitle_blue());
        holder.cardPrice.setTextColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
        holder.cardName.setTextColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Is it only the image that's wrong? or the text too?

Comment: Yes ,it is image only .

Comment: So you mean that getView is getting called with position 2 but the row appears as position 3 for example?

Comment: can you try to describe your problem more clearer?  What's about getView() is called with repeated positions due to the first card not showing the correct image?

Comment: @xxxzhi  Yes , I have total 7 cards in the ListView , What is happening ,getView() first calls with position 0-6 ,and this sequence is repeating again and again .

Comment: I don't know the reason. this is a very nice question. Do you have tried to remove the image init code from getView and then watch the call times?

Comment: Yes , when I use same code to set image as I have used for "Kiss" card ,then it is working fine .

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872996/best-way-to-handle-multiple-getview-calls-from-inside-an-adapter).  'there is absolutely no guarantee on the order in which getView() will be called nor how many times'

Comment: @xxxzhi I have visited this solution and tried to fix the issue , but no luck .

Comment: you just suffer from repeat call getview, but there is no affect about application. Is right?

Comment: @AndroidDev I still don't understand what your problem is. Do all the items have a wrong image? Or just the first one? What exactly do you observe?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will fix the issue, but I'd suggest to always use `Picasso`, including the case of the 'Kiss' cards, because it has its own way to handle cancellation of image download in case of view recycling (see https://square.github.io/picasso/ for more details)

That can be done by replacing

```
holder.cardIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
```

by

```
Picasso.load(R.drawable.logo).into(holder.cardIcon);
```

Comment: thank you for your efforts , I have tried your suggestion but it didn't help me .

Comment: Could you edit your question and describe more clearly what exactly is happening?